# AngularJS - jQueryUI slider values reflection on models

Tags: angularjs

I have the following directive:

```
directive('yearSlider', function(Filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',          // must be an element
        transclude: false,      // don't preserve content
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.$watch('yearMin + yearMax', function(newVal, oldVal) {
                if(newVal === oldVal) return; // skip initialization

                $("#year-slider").slider("option", "min", parseInt($scope.yearMin));
                $("#year-slider").slider("option", "max", parseInt($scope.yearMax));
                $("#year-slider").slider("value", $("#year-slider").slider("value"));
            });
        },
        link: function postLink($scope, $element) {
            $element.slider({
                range: true,
                min: 1900,
                max: new Date().getFullYear(),
                values: [ 1900, new Date().getFullYear() ],
                slide: function(event, ui) {
                    $scope.yearFrom = ui.values[0];
                    $scope.yearTo = ui.values[1];
                    $scope.$apply();
                },
                change: function(event, ui) {
                    $scope.yearFrom = ui.values[0];
                    $scope.yearTo = ui.values[1];
                    Filter.apply($scope);
                }
            });
        },
        template:
            '<div id="year-slider"></div>',
        replace: true
    }
}).
```

This directive is used in a view and it renders a slider correctly.

I'm assigning both values of the slider to two models `yearFrom` and `yearTo` to get the range of years specified by the slider. In some cases, I need to change the min/max values of the slider and that's what I'm doing in the `controller` above.

The issue here is that I'm watching for both values `yearMin` and `yearMax` and these two models change consecutively which leads to the controller and `change` of `$element.slider` executing twice.

What I'm trying to achieve is to execute this once but the fact that I have two models makes it logically impossible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out while writing the question, I simply changed my model to:

```
$scope.years = { min: data.yearMin, max: data.yearMax }
```

And changed my $watch to:

```
$scope.$watch('years', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if(newVal === oldVal) return; // skip initialization

    $("#year-slider").slider("option", "min", parseInt($scope.years.min));
    $("#year-slider").slider("option", "max", parseInt($scope.years.max));
    $("#year-slider").slider("value", $("#year-slider").slider("value"));
});
```

Putting JQuery slider aside, this is a common issue that faced me with AngularJS, particularly having many models firing multiple events to watchers while I needed them to fire once. I believe grouping them in a similar fashion (if applicable) would solve this issue.

Comment: You posted a question and then answered your own question in less than 60 seconds? :|

Comment: @keyboardSmasher fast fingers are fast!